# Nested map to sequence of tuples representing edges in Clojure

Tags: graph, clojure, tree, traversal

How might one go about expressing the following transformation in idiomatic Clojure?

```
(def m
     {:a {:b {:c nil
              :d nil}
          :e nil}})


(map->edges m) ; =>


([:a :b] [:b :c] [:b :d] [:e nil] [:d nil] [:a :e] [:e nil])
```

I don't care about the order in which vectors appear in the result, so either depth-first or breath-first search strategies are fine.

Comment: FWIW the input format is not really a very good way of representing a graph, since it is not clear how cycles will work. More typical is something like an adjacency map, where the keys are nodes and values are sets of nodes. For your graph, that would look like `'{a #{b e}, b #{c d}}`, optionally with empty sets for c/d/e to indicate nodes with no outgoing edges. Ideally I would say to fix your input format so you don't have to do this step, but if you can't control it then the answers to this question are a reasonable way to post-process it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can express this fairly concisely using [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) and [`tree-seq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq):

```
(defn map->edges [m]
  (for [entry m
        [x m] (tree-seq some? val entry)
        y (or (keys m) [m])]
    [x y]))
```

Example:

```
(map->edges m)
;;=> ([:a :b] [:a :e] [:b :c] [:b :d] [:c nil] [:d nil] [:e nil])
```

Comment: Although this answers the specific example in the question. be aware this code throws an exception on non-nil leaf nodes.